# VERBOSE-2:platform_view.cc(81):Failed to create platform view rendering surface

Tags: flutter

When I update flutter SDK from v1.12.13+hotfix.5 to v1.24.0-8.0.pre.My flutter app cannot work in iOS.
This is error log:

```
2020-11-19 10:45:49.927339+0800 Runner[355:22342] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2020-11-19 10:45:49.927614+0800 Runner[355:22342] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-11-19 10:45:50.066676+0800 Runner[355:22342] [VERBOSE-2:platform_view.cc(81)] Failed to 
create platform view rendering surface
020-11-19 10:45:50.103803+0800 Runner[355:22540] flutter: Observatory listening on 
http://127.0.0.1:52306/RAcRjVg3wOk=/
```

flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.24.0-8.0.pre.252, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73
darwin-x64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
! Error: iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPhone is
connected. (code -13)
• No issues found!
```

Comment: Have you tried running flutter clean and restarting the IDE?

Comment: Yeah,I tried all the methods I can think of, but to no avail

Comment: Any news on this? I have the same problem